# I want to swap items in the diagonals of a matrix in a custom matrix class

Tags: java, matrix

I want to create a method that can swap items in the diagonals of a matrix in my custom matrix class.

If this is the input:

```
1,0,0,5
0,2,6,0
0,7,3,0
8,0,0,4
```

This would be the output:

```
4,0,0,8
0,3,7,0
0,6,2,0
5,0,0,1
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Matrix
{
public final static int MAX_INTEGER = 50;
    public final static int MAX_SIZE = 20;

    private int[][] matrix;


    public Matrix(int[][] matrix)
    {
        if (matrix.length >= 0 && matrix.length <= MAX_SIZE)
            this.matrix = matrix;
        else if (matrix.length < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("The length of the array can not be negative");
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("The length of the array can not be greater than 20");

        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            for (int j=0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                matrix[i][j] = generator.nextInt(MAX_INTEGER)+1;
    }


    public void swapDiagonals()
    {   
        int aux=0;


        for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            for (int j=0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                if(i == j)
                {                 
                    aux = matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[matrix.length-1-i][matrix.length-1-j];
                    matrix[matrix.length-1-i][matrix.length-1-j] = aux;
                }

        for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            for (int j=0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                if(i == matrix.length-j)
                {   
                    aux = matrix[i][matrix.length-1-j];
                    matrix[i][matrix.length-1-j] = matrix[matrix.length-1-i][j];
                    matrix[matrix.length-1-i][j] = aux;
                }    


    }
```

The thing is that the method doesn't do anything. If I check the matrix after I run the method, nothing has changed.

This should be a succesful outcome:

```
    @Test
    public void testSwapDiagonals()
    {
        Matrix dummy = new Matrix(new int[4][4]);
        assertEquals(int[][]={{13,15,23,6},{17,37,15,6},{10,7,48,45},{4,47,41,21}}, dummy.getMatrix());
        dummy.swapDiagonals();
        assertEquals(int[][]={{21,15,23,4},{17,48,7,6},{10,15,37,45},{6,47,41,13}}, dummy.getMatrix());
    }
```

Sorry, I should have been more specific: I don't want to swap all diagonals. I want [this](https://gyazo.com/df41914bb15c853e59718e43496c122b)

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem lies in your `main` method. `swapDiagonals()` seems fine. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by main method, im programming in bluej if that helps. Eliminiating the second set of loops still doesn't change anything in the matrix

Comment: when you are printing you matrix which matrix do you use ? I think your problem is there !...

Comment: You need a main method to run call and run this code.

Comment: Where are you calling `swapDiagonals()`? You need something along the lines of `Matrix m = new Matrix(myMatrix); m.swapDiagonals(); int[][] swappedMatrix = m.getMatrix(); print(m);`.

Comment: @StackFlowed if both matrix are pointing to the same memory address it is not a problem

Comment: @dreamcrash Not in bluej, you can run methods directly. A better question would be how he is launching the code

Comment: @StevenLowes my bad.

Comment: @dreamcrash f both matrix are pointing to the same memory address it is not a problem agreed but i have a feeling in his case they are not.

Comment: The matrix is generated randomly. And never created a main method before. I'm not currently executing programs, just creating classes.

Comment: @DiegoGutiérrezLópez How do you see the values of the matrix to know that it hasn't changed?

Comment: Where do you allocate the matrix that you give as the argument of public Matrix(int[][] matrix) ?

Comment: Bluej is really basic, I don't need to allocate the matrix, I can just call the constructor and write the parameter directly, and by just clicking the object I can see all its values

Comment: So you call the constructor, then check the values (note that the values are all randomly generated in the constructor - so only the size of the matrix matters), then call `swapDiagonals()`, then check values again, and see no change?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Maybe I can create a test for it.

Comment: I created the test and added it to the post. But instead of doing that, when i call getMatrix() the second time, the matrix doesn't change

Comment: Why is it so difficult for you to post your code of your main showing how you invoke the swap method?

Comment: main method probably is fine, your swaping loops works funky

Comment: Because of how bluej works, i don't have code to invoke the swap method, i just press a button and the method is invoked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, swaps diagonals of square shaped matrix

```
public void swapMatrixDiagonals() {

    int up = 0; //Can be replaced by variable 'i' in loop
    int down = matrix.length - 1;
    int left = 0; //Can be replaced by variable 'i' in loop
    int right = matrix[matrix.length - 1].length - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length / 2; i++) {
        int tempLeft = matrix[up][left];
        int tempRight = matrix[up][right];

        matrix[up][left] = matrix[down][right];
        matrix[down][right] = tempLeft;

        matrix[up][right] = matrix[down][left];
        matrix[down][left] = tempRight;

        left++;
        right--;
        up++;
        down--;
    }
}
```

variable "up" and "left" are here only to better visualise what code is doing, can be replaced by incrementing "i" in loop

Note that it can produce "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" 
if the matrix won't be square
e.g.

```
A B C D
E - - -
F G H I
J K L M
```

---

If You want to swap all the positions there's need for more loops, here's an example code for such an operation

```
public void swap() {
    int up = 0; //Can be replaced with variable 'i' in loop
    int down = matrix.length - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        int left = 0; //Can be replaced with variable 'j' in loop
        int right = matrix[i].length - 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length / 2; j++) {
            int temp = matrix[i][left];
            matrix[i][left] = matrix[i][right];
            matrix[i][right] = temp;
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length / 2; i++) {
        int[] temp = matrix[up];
        matrix[up] = matrix[down];
        matrix[down] = temp;
        up++;
        down--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just realised something, I should have been more specific, but i don't want to change all the diagonals. [link](https://gyazo.com/df41914bb15c853e59718e43496c122b)

Comment: explain what you want to accomplish and we can work something out.

Comment: Just edited the main post, I used zeros in the example because they were irrelevant

Comment: Just got my own solution based on your last post. Thanks for all the help